# Is this a class based on map? or maybe class with two types?

Tags: dart, flutter

On a `flutter` [example project](https://github.com/boeledi/blocs/blob/master/lib/bloc_helpers/bloc_event_state.dart) I stumbled upon those lines:

```
abstract class BlocEvent extends Object {}
abstract class BlocState extends Object {}

abstract class BlocEventStateBase<BlocEvent, BlocState> {}
```

Is this a class based on map? or maybe class with two types?

What is the meaning of `<BlocEvent, BlocState>`?

Comment: It's wrong code, no need to define abstract class BlocEvent,BlocState. The below is Generic class. The above BlocState & the below BlocState are not related at all

Comment: @yelliver thx, good to know. Non the less, I still dont understand what is the meaning of `class WhatEver<x, y> {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [generic type declaration](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#generics), but as @yelliver pointed out, the example you posted is not correct, since `BlocEvent` and `BlocState` inside `<>` are just interpreted as generic type identifiers (unrelated to the classes with the same name).

This would make sense:

```
abstract class BlocEvent extends Object {}
abstract class BlocState extends Object {}

abstract class BlocEventStateBase<T extends BlocEvent, S extends BlocState> {}
```

Also, note that there are [conventions](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-follow-existing-mnemonic-conventions-when-naming-type-parameters) for naming type parameters.